# Using While Loop in __init__ to meet specific condition in Python

Tags: python, oop, random, conditional-statements

I am working with a senior developer who pointed out that the below code written is not the best practice.

```
import random


class RandomNumbers:

    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_TEXT = ''' {} + {} '''
        while True:
            self.A = random.randint(1, 10)
            self.B = random.randint(1, 5)

            if self.A > self.B:
                break

    def generate(self):
        return self.BASE_TEXT(self.A, self.B)
```

I want to ensure that random number `A` is always greater than random number `B`. To meet this condition I can't think of any other way apart from using while with an if condition.

The comment I got from the senior developer is that

Neither do I understand what he means by that nor do I see any problems with code with an API response.

> you cannot have something that runs randomly on the class constructor,
> especially since we will need an API response for it

Can someone please review the code and validate that there is no issue with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The senior developer is correct that when unlucky, your code can randomly and potentially take a long time to run if `self.A > self.B` keeps getting evaluated to `False`.

Instead, you can make A the stop number of [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) when generating a random number for B, or 6, whichever is lower. But since A has to be greater than B and B must be at least 1, A should be at least 2:

```
class RandomNumbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_TEXT = ''' {} + {} '''
        self.A = random.randint(2, 10)
        self.B = random.randrange(1, min(self.A, 6))

    def generate(self):
        # don't forget to call the str.format method
        return self.BASE_TEXT.format(self.A, self.B)
```